# What Paper Format do Boarding Passes use?

Tags: boarding

I'm looking at creating some Boarding Passes for my Virtual Airline called "Zelandas". After looking at websites like the SITA website, Wikipedia, and more, I cannot seem to find what format of paper is used for a Boarding Pass.

When I am talking about Format, I mean something like A4, or B5 etc.

Where would I be able to purchase this kind of paper, not in bulk?

Thanks, Will

Comment: Send the boarding pass to a smart phone. Ryanair allows printing of your own boarding pass. It's a PDF and the A4 page folds to A6 (quarter) size for pocket storage.

Comment: I'm not sure boarding pass' format is normalized. Moreover, this question may be better suited on [travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a better fit on Travel.SE

Answer (score 8):

Standard boarding passes are the size of an IBM punchcard, ​7⅜ by ​3¼ inches (187.325 mm × 82.55 mm) because paper and printers in that size were readily available at the time, and then inertia kept the size the same even when punchcards fell out of use and it became a specialty item.

Many airlines have switched to rolls of 3⅛ inch (79.375 mm) thermal paper, as is now commonly used in cash registers. For a new system, this is probably less expensive and easier to prototype.